# Doubts with cleverhans FastGradientMethod (FGM), adversarial image generation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent, multiclass-classification

I have a keras model (CNN with final softmax) that is an RGB image classifier. Output of the model are 5 possible categories for input images (one-hot encoded).
I'm trying to generate adversarial images for my keras model with the *Cleverhans* ([tensorflow library](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans)).

A simplified version of my code which generates one adversarial image is the following:

```
# model is the CNN keras model
wrap = KerasModelWrapper(model)
fgsm = FastGradientMethod(wrap, sess=session)
fgsm_params = {'eps': 16. / 256,
               'clip_min': 0.,
               'clip_max': 1.
               }
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, img_rows, img_cols,
                                      nchannels))
adv_x = fgsm.generate(x, **fgsm_params)
# original image is a tensor containing only one RGB image, shape=(1,48,48,3) 
adv_image = adv_x.eval(session=session, feed_dict={x: original_image})
```

**Chapter 1, eps**

From my understanding, *'eps'* FGM param is the input variation step (minimum change for one image value/pixel).

I have observed that the final outcome is highly affected by *eps*, sometimes I need high *eps* in order to obtain an effective adversarial image, an image which effectively changes the category label in respect to the original image.

With low *eps* sometimes FGM fails to obtain a working adversarial image i.e., having an image O, with label l<sub>O</sub> FGM fails to produce adversarial image O' with l<sub>O'</sub>!= l<sub>O</sub>, e.g., for l<sub>O</sub> = [0,0,1,0,0] we still obtain l<sub>O'</sub> = [0,0,1,0,0], failing to generate an adversarial image with a different label.

Questions (I'm sorry the problem requires a set of questions):

- Does FGM always find out a working adversarial image? i.e., Is it normal that FGM fails?
- Is there a way to obtain an estimated quality of the generated adversarial image (without predicting with model)?
- Why is the value of eps step so important?
- Most important: **Is there a way to tell FGM to try harder searching for the adversarial image(e.g, more steps)?**

**Chapter 2, y,y_target**

I have also experimented *y* and *y_target* params. 
Can you also explain me what are the params `'y'`, `'y_target'`?

I thought `'y_target'` tells that we want to generate an adversarial image that targets a specific category. 
For example I thought that `y_target = [[0,1,0,0,0]]` in `feed_dict` should force to generate an adversarial image which is classified with the 2th class from the model.

- Am I right? ..or
- do I miss something?

P.s: my problem is that setting y_target fails to produce adversarial images.

please give me few tips.. ;-)
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answers from *Cleverhans* developers on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/issues/589), I quote their answer here:

**Chapter 1:**

FGSM (like any attack) is not guaranteed to find an adversarial image that is misclassified by the model because it makes approximations when solving the optimization problem that defines an adversarial example.

The attack can fail to find adversarial images for various reasons, one common reason is gradient masking. You can read about it in this [blog pos](http://www.cleverhans.io/security/privacy/ml/2017/02/15/why-attacking-machine-learning-is-easier-than-defending-it.html)t and in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02697) as well as this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00420).

The *eps* step is important because it is the magnitude of the perturbation. The attack first computes the direction in which to perturb the image (using gradients of the model) and then takes a step of size *eps* in that direction. Hence, *eps* corresponds roughly to what intuitively one would think of the "power" of the attack.

You can find a multi-step variant of FGSM in `BasicIterativeMethod`

**Chapter 2:**

*y* is used to specify labels in the case of an untargeted attack (any wrong class is considered as success for the adversary) whereas *y_target* is used to specify a target class in the targeted attack case (the adversary is successful only if the model makes a particular misclassification in a chosen class).

It is often the case that targeted attacks require more perturbation (i.e., higher *eps* values in the FGSM case) than untargeted attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little detail to the accepted answer from @Fabiano:

*Does FGM always find out a working adversarial image? i.e., Is it normal that FGM fails?*

- No, FGSM does not necessarily always find a working adversarial image. Depending on the exact task and other factors, it may or may not succeed. FGSM is basically just a "fast" way to generate adversarial examples. It is not in any way guaranteed to be optimal. In practice, iterative attacks (such as the Basic Iterative Method as suggested by @Fabiano above, and the very popular Projected Gradient Descent (PGD) attack) are usually much more effective than FGSM, which involves a single step.

*Is there a way to obtain an estimated quality of the generated adversarial image (without predicting with model)?*

- You could always use image quality metrics to compare the original image to its perturbed counterpart. For example, you can compute the PSNR or SSIM between the two, which will give you a quantitative/numeric measure of the *visual* difference between the two. But translating that numeric measure to a subjective one is a different matter entirely. On the other hand, if you meant whether you can assess whether or not the generated adversarial example is successful or not without passing it through the model, I do not think so.

*Why is the value of eps step so important?*

- Already answered by @Fabiano above. But as an additional note: imagine a 2D map where one "region" belongs to one class and the other "region" belongs to some other class. For simplicity assume we have an island surrounded by water. Water is one class and the island is another class in the model's decision space (we assume binary classification for simplicity).

A very small eps may not allow the adversarial image cross into a different class region/boundary (i.e. a sample in the water region may still end up in the water region after perturbation because it didn't travel far enough, and the same for a sample on the island). One that is too large may cause the adversarial sample to overshoot the desired region and end up back in the same class region, albeit in a different position (the sample moves from water, over land, and lands in water again).

*Most important: Is there a way to tell FGM to try harder searching for the adversarial image(e.g, more steps)?*

- Not really. By design FGSM is a "single-step" attack, so it only ever takes a single step in the direction it thinks will cause misclassification. But as @Fabiano mentioned above, there are iterative attacks (such as the Basic Iterative Method, which is basically an iterative FGSM) which attack over a number of steps which you can increase if desired.